# EF Model Circular Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model

In an EF & MVC project I have objects for the following in my model

- Survey, which has many

  - Steps, which has many

    - Questions, which has one

      - AnswerGroup, which has many

        - Answers

AnswerGroups are generic and can have a relationships with many questions.

This all works fine but now I need the ability for a question and answer combination to have a child question associated with it and I'm not sure how to set this up in the model.

UPDATE

I've done this in the configuration for the Answer object

```
        HasMany(m => m.Questions).WithMany(x => x.Answers).Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("QuestionId");
            m.MapRightKey("AnswerId");
            m.ToTable("AnswerQuestion");
        });
```

This creates the AnswerQuestion table but both fields are foreign keys on the Answer tables Id column which doesn't help at all.

Comment: have you tried, adding a ChildQuestionID to Answer and add it as a Foreign Key to Question?  EF is pretty good at handling circular logic, it can even handle self referencing FKs.

Comment: also is this DB first or Code first?

Comment: A ChildQuestionId on the Answer object won't work as that answer could belong to many questions. The child question needs to relate to a combination of a Question_Id and Answer_Id combination.

Comment: hmm, not sure how you want to use it, you could try a many to many table, with three rows, QuestionID, AnswerID, and ChildQustionID.  the first two should be FK to their respective tables, this should allow you to access them via navigation properties, the trick would be, if you access the nav property off Question you would need to filter only child questions for each given answer, and you'd probably have to do that in your business logic, or repository, which may not be ideal.

Comment: Madullah, thanks for looking at this, I have updated the question to provide more info.